# how to use if with string in Settings c#

Tags: c#, if-statement, settings

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.BG == 1)
{               
}
```

I think there is something I need to write before (1) but I don't know

[image]

Comment: "Operator == cannot be applied to operands of type `string` and `int`". Did you try to Google that?

Answer (score 1):

To represent a string, you need to surround the value with double quotes. Currently you're comparing it to an integer. Instead, do something like this:

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.BG == "1")
{               
}
```

Another way to do this would be to call the built-in `ToString()` method that belongs to all objects:

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.BG == 1.ToString())
{               
}
```